Use of the word double
I’m struggling a bit using the word “double” and fully knowing what it means. In one dictionary that I like to use it gives an example sentence.

One of the eggs had a double yolk.

I get what this what means, but what if you make yolk plural and the sentence is

One of the eggs had double yolks.

Does this mean that the egg had multiple yolks with a double yolk?
Another sentence confuses me that dictionary gives as well.

Go through those double doors and walk to the end of the hall.

I feel like double doors are more than 2 doors and that it should be like the last example I gave where in this case there are multiple doors that have a double door.

A single doorway may have two doors, i.e. double doors. But the word "door" (or in this case "doors") is often used to mean "doorway". Otherwise going through a door would be painful and destructive.

What seems to be confusing you is that we sometimes use the singular after double, as in double yolk, and sometimes plural, as in double doors.

You could find out how eggs come to have double yolks.  Often English usage expresses reality. Thus whether double is followed  by a plural may reflect the real world.  Double yolk, double doors, double rows?

How would an egg have multiple double yolks?

In all cases, what "double" means is a matter of definition, taking "double" as a single word or as a non-analysable part of a combination.
In the case of "yolk", the definition of the adjective is the following.

(OLD) twice as much or as many as usual
a double helping
a double espresso
two double whiskies
a double lesson of English

When you say "a double yolk" or  "a double-yolk egg" you are talking about a single egg in which are found two yolks. You do not find "double yolks egg".


However, you find almost uniquely "double yolks" when the context involves more than one egg.

(Iniquities of Gulch Fork - Bob Smith, ‎Sara Rhodes · 2016) "Yes, most of my Neighbors buy eggs here. My chickens are laying eggs with double yolks right now. People seem to really like them."  "I know we like eggs with double yolks," Mary affirmed.

(Amber Frost - Suzi Davis · 2011) "At breakfast this morning, all of the eggs had double yolks," I repeated as I scrambled to my feet.

(The Art of Uncertainty: How to Navigate Chance, Ignorance, ... -
David Spiegelhalter · 2024) As an illustration, of the caution needed before plunging into a complex calculation, consider another classic coincicence story that appears regularly on no-news days, which concerns someone who has bought a box of large eggs and found they have  all double yolks.


Occasionally, "a double yolk" is used.

(Homesteading From Scratch: Building Your Self-Sufficient ...
Steven Jones · 2017) —Sometimes eggs have a double yolk.

There are only rare cases of "double yolks" being used to mean one single double yolk.

(The More the Merrier: Celebrating Seventy
Judy Pollard Smith · 2019) Cracked my egg this morning to find twins. Twin eggs. Double yolks. The next one was the same.

(The Grammarians: A Novel - Cathleen Schine · 2019) Double yolks mean double embryos. Double embryos take up double space Inside the egg.


As concerns "double door", the combination is analysable according to the following OLD definition.

(OLD) with two parts
​>
having or made of two things or parts that are equal or similar
double doors
a double-page advertisement
‘Otter’ is spelt with a double t.
My extension is two four double 0 (2400).
a high-profile double murder case
Olympic double gold medallist Mo Farah

However, it seems that the SOED has the final word on this; this is not an analyzable combination.

(SOED) double door(s) (a) a pair of doors side by side in an opening, meeting in the middle. (b) Two doors situated one close behind the other.

In the case of a combination like "double bluff", for instance there is no reasonning (analyzing) that can explain it; this is a noun with its own definition.

(OLD) double bluff noun
​a way of trying to trick somebody by telling them the truth while hoping that they think you are lying


I suspect some of the OP's confusion might also come from how we don't (usually, but do sometimes) use noun plurals adjectivally.

Trying to brainstorm plural "doubles" besides "doors," tennis comes to mind...
